# Bicubic spline interpolation solver

Tags: interpolation

I created a small delphi application to solver bicubic spline interpolation problem.
I have a grid of 4x4 functions value and I want use bicubic spline interpolation to get value for x, y point.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicubic_interpolation

I need to do some tests.
Is there same online solver or free application to compare my results with these? I think Scilab can help me but I cannot understand how use it for bicubic spline interpolation.

Comment: I don't use Scilab, but the documentation points to the function `splin2d` for the function to obtain the coefficients, and `interp2d` to evaluate the spline at any points using the coefficients found earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look [here](https://www2.units.it/ipl/students_area/imm2/files/Numerical_Recipes.pdf). In page 125, you will find a piece of code and good explanations.

For more information, have a look [here](http://numerical.recipes/).